# Keep geting "Missing semicolon" in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to learn React and I keep getting the error "Syntax Error. Missng semicolon." Can you please help me what's wrong? Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  onPressButton() {
    alert('You tapped the button!')
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Button onPress={this.onPressButton} title="Press Me" color="#841584"/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: For future questions please paste the entire error message as it contains much information you didn't provide, for example the line number etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
onPressButton() {
  alert('You tapped the button!')
}
```

Should be

```
function onPressButton() {
  alert('You tapped the button!');
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the `function` keyword should be the issue here, but the `;` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Semicolons are totally optional in JS and therefore React as well. There must be a style config in your project that is causing these errors. I would ask your team if this is not a side project how that was setup.

On an unrelated note: I would define your styles above your app function. Functions in JavaScript are hoisted when your script runs. Constants are not. In general you should never call something before it's defined as that can lead to difficult bugs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing semicolon after that `alert`

Edit: Anyway, the error should tell you the line, or appear over it

Comment: A semicolon is optional, the issue is the missing `function` keyword for the `onPressButton` function.